# responsive-loader only returns a data url

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, responsive-images, responsive-loader

I am trying to use [responsive-loader](https://github.com/dazuaz/responsive-loader) in my vue/node project, but it only returns a data url.

I installed with

```
npm install responsive-loader sharp --save-dev
```

Here is my `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('responsive')
            .test(/\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$/i)
            .use('responsive-loader')
            .loader('responsive-loader')
            .tap(() => {
                return {
                    adapter: require('responsive-loader/sharp'),
                }
            })
    },
}
```

In one of my components I have

```js
let responsiveImage = require('../assets/image.jpg')
console.log(responsiveImage)
```

And the output of the log statement is this data url image of a small white square:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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)
```

I expected it to be an object with `src` and a few other porperties.

Why isn't it loading my image?

## Update

The problem was (as mentioned my Michael Levy) that my rule was never reached because an existing rule for all images came first. To fix this, I added `.before('images')` to my rule, so it would check my rule first.

One other issue was that for some reason `npm` had changed my `vue-cli` to version 3.x without me noticing. Because of this, I was getting an error that `.before()` was not a function. After running `vue upgrade`, and changing to version 4.x, it started working.

I also added `.resourceQuery(/srcset/)` so it would only affect images I specifically wanted it to.

My new `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('responsive')
            .before('images')
            .test(/\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$/i)
            // if the import url looks like "some.png?srcset..."
            .resourceQuery(/srcset/)
            .use('responsive-loader')
            .loader('responsive-loader')
            .tap(() => {
                return {
                    adapter: require('responsive-loader/sharp'),
                }
            })
    },
}
```

Comment: Is this still working for you with the latest updates? I've implemented your solution, without the `resourceQuery`, and I am still receiving the base64 string.

Comment: I have not updated any versions in that project, so I can't say if a newer version has broken my solution. You could try using Vue/cli v4.x. Or maybe you have another rule besides `images` that is executing first. Also, try with the `resourceQuery` just in case that was necessary.

Comment: I have still the same problem. Did you find a solution? I also tried to replace/remove the original `images` rules as explained by @michal-levý . The config from `vue inspect --mode production` looks OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding new rule for images but projects generated/managed by Vue CLI already have rule for images and this rule has a precedence as it is added 1st

You can find the default rule by looking at [the code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/70afd90ca357ee93823c61ccb1378d5f00eb063a/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/assets.js#L36) or by running `vue inspect` command and checking the output.

[Here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#replacing-loaders-of-a-rule) is the documentation on how to remove the original `images` rule